# ID3tag - Script for extracting metadata from filename

Tags: shell-script, file-metadata

I have directory of recording with

```
foo - bar-202009.opus
unix - tilde-2020se.opus
stack - exchange-29328f.opus
```

I trying to set meta from file name
for `foo - bar.202009.opus`
(there are some inconsistency with -
so easy way is scrapping `-<6digitchars>.opus`)

```
song title = foo - bar
```

Using sed to scrap,

```
$ ls | sed 's/-[a-zA-Z0-9]*\w//g; s/.opus//g'

foo - bar
unix - tilde
stack - exchange
```

I use id3tag to set, synatx

```
id3tag --song=[tilte] [file]
```

I have all those in directory, so iterating with while & read,

```
ls | while read x; \
    do id3tag \
    $(echo \
    --song=\"$(echo $x | sed 's/-[a-zA-Z0-9]*\w//g; s/.opus//g')\"  \
    \"${x}\"
    ); \
    done
```

problem with above is, the spaces in input file causes id3 to interpret as another file (even when
enclosed with `\"${x}\"`)

so output right now,

```
foo
'bar"'
'"bar-202009.opus"'
.
.
```

Is there a way for i3dtag to see file with spaces as a single file.

Comment: Avoid parsing `ls` https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoiding `ls` parse, one-liner.

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in *; do
    scrap="$(echo $file | sed 's/-[a-zA-Z0-9]*\w//g; s/.opus//g')"
    id3tag --song="${scrap}" "${f}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you not try to make it a one-liner:

```bsh
ls | while read x; do
    x="$(echo $x | sed 's/-[a-zA-Z0-9]*\w//g; s/.opus//g')"
    id3tag --song="${x}"
done
```

The point annahri made about not parsing `ls` output is a good one, so you could instead  do

```bsh
for x in *.opus; do
 .... the rest is the same
```

With this approach, there are fewer places for the quotes to get consumed by a sub-shell or for the quotes to be passed as a literal to `id3tag`.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, doesn't solve my problem of passing input to `id3tag`

Comment: @Hisacro I notice that your answer is almost identical to this in terms of breaking the one-liner into multiple calls and doing the parsing before invoking `id3tag`.  I'm glad you found it useful.

Comment: thought it's identical, there's no way(?) to parse second argument `"${file_input}"` to i3tags (spaces always break as new file guess that's how the ls works). If you have figured with `ls` I'll accept your answer without regrets.

Comment: if you think about it, whole script is pointless without file input (ie. second argument)

Comment: @Hisacro point taken, I didn't notice the second parameter in your original post.